# How to make an outbound request to users to update their passwords?

Tags: passwords, password-management, password-policy, disclosure

Clearly it works best if the request to update a password happens as a response to an **inbound request** to access a known system, but how do you make an outbound request to users to update their passwords?

Comment: You mean like Sony, LinkedIn, Yahoo, et. al. have done in the past year?

Comment: @Iszi: Correct; their consultants must have had practices for making outbound requests.

Answer (score 5):

### Technical half: changing the password

The simple and secure way is a round-about, "You don't."

When a user logs in with their old password, display a notice saying they must reset their password. Generate an email with a reset token and send it to their email address. The email address token must be used because we no longer trust the password (and we hope that the email address is still under a users' control).

### Human half: discussing a breach

If you're requesting users update their passwords, it may be because you're changing hashing algorithms. That really should happen behind the scenes, or involve reclaiming old accounts rather than leaving them dormant. It *probably* is because you've encountered a breach, though.

Breaches affect customers even if you don't hold any sensitive information because online presences are often linked (same username, email address, etc.) and because passwords are often re-used. If you've lost control of your password database, users may be at risk of having those passwords brute-forced and then used against accounts from other sites.

Regardless of your motivation, the technical method of changing passwords remains the same. If you've had a breach, though, disclosing that is important for your ethical duty to your users and sometimes for legal requirements depending on your jurisdiction. How the letter is written is a combination entirely of legal and subjective matters, but it should explain why users may need to be concerned about other accounts and why they need to reset their password on their next login.

Comment: -1 Oddly, you're the user that lead to me posting this; randomly clicked your profile before the post, and saw your most recent post on [Linkedin](http://storyinmemo.com/?p=98) thought I'd ask a question about it. Given how many users reuse passwords, find it hard to believe the best practice is to wait for the user to login, or organically hear they need to reset their passwords; use passwords in the plural, since I assume the average user uses their password on more than one account. Gave the -1 since you said the best answer is not to do anything until the user uses the password.

Comment: @blunders too much time in the terminal today... :(

Comment: Me, or you... :-)

Comment: @blunders Well, are you asking about the technical part of how to deal with requiring a password change, or with the human part of disclosing a breach? It seems like you already know **why** a breach needs a notification.

Comment: Really don't have an answer in mind; guessing that answer would likely be based on practices in jurisdictions that require by law that users be notified. And yes, believe everyone that knows about password resuse would understand why a breach needs a notification.

Comment: @blunders - You could generate a new password in a new field and use both fields up until the next time the password is used.  Once that happens have them choose a new password and chang the new password field, and delete the old password field, this forces the user's hand.  Outside of doing this I am not sure what else you CAN do, changing it for them and sending them the password, is worst then having passwords stored in plaintext.

Comment: @Ramhound: Thanks for the feedback. Have you read the answers currently posted? Also, don't understand what the function of the "new password" would be, please explain more if possible. Again, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Obviously, if you want to send a request to users (without waiting for them to come back), then you have to contact them in some way, which, most of the time, means sending emails. This works only if you know of a valid email address for each user (which is a good reason for verifying the email address when the user first registers).

Thanks to spammers and other villains with fraudulent intentions, typical users are *trained* to disregard emails which talk about passwords. This is your biggest problem. Similarly, you do not really want to reverse that training. So it would be bad practice to send an email with a clickable link to a password reset page: the security-aware users will not follow the link, and the others just so demonstrate how vulnerable they are.

---

Let's try another way. Usually, when you need users to do a mass-reset of the passwords, it is because it is suspected, for some contextual reason, that a substantial number of user passwords may be compromised. For instance, someone broke into your server and grabbed a copy of the database of hashed passwords.

Compromised passwords are an issue because they allow unauthorized reentry. Conversely, compromised passwords are *not* an issue (at least, not for your server) until the attacker tries to come back. This means that you can, somehow, wait. Technically, this involves the following:

- You configure your server so that every successful login is redirected to a password reset page (I assume a Web server here). The user is not permitted to access any other service before the password is reset.
- The "password reset page" is actually a pre-reset page: the user can click on a button, which makes the server send him (by mail) a transient, user-specific link to the true password reset page.
- The true password reset page, as its name says, allows the user the reset his password.
- *Optionally*, you proactively send an email to every user to warn them about the issue, and to courteously (but firmly) suggest that they should reset their password in the near future. No clickable link, please !

This setup is "secure" as long as we assume that the attacker did not guess a user's password *and* compromised the user's email at the same time.

The relevance of sending a mass email depends on the situation: it may be good for public relations ("see, we are taking security seriously, and we do not want to hide the issues") and it can be bad for public relations ("we got hacked, it is embarrassing"). The current zeitgeist is that, on a general basis, the email should be sent; denying issues has a high probability of making them only worse. Admit your misfortune, eat your hat, and beg for forgiveness -- users will forgive you if they feel that you treat them "fairly" (i.e. you use a lot of flattery). Also, as you indicate, users tend to reuse passwords, so while this is not technically your problem, a proactive warning will be felt as a positive gesture.

If your server is big enough, hire a public relations specialist right away, to handle the crisis.

Answer (score 0):

About your only option, if you don't want to wait for your users' next login, is to send your users an email and ask them to log in.  That's a bit dubious: your users may delete the email as spam/phishing.

Alternatively, you can disable every user account on your site, and the next time they log in, require them to go through some special extra process to authenticate themselves.  In addition to requiring them to provide their password, you might also require them to solve a CAPTCHA or ask them some questions about their account activity (e.g., for an email provider, ask them to provide the email addresses of a few correspondents that the user regularly contacts).  Or, you might perform some other checks.  None of this is ideal, but hey, you asked.